# Mockito cannot seem to mock slf4j interface

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, slf4j

I'm trying to make a wrapper for an slf4j `Logger` interface and test it, but I keep getting the following error.

```
TestDebugLog FAILED
    Wanted but not invoked:
    logger.debug("some message", "arg1", "arg2");
    -> at com.common.TrebuchetLoggerTest.TestDebugLog(TrebuchetLoggerTest.java:37)

    However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
    logger.debug("some message", "arg1", "arg2");
    -> at com.common.TrebuchetLogger.debug(TrebuchetLogger.java:19)
        at com.common.TrebuchetLoggerTest.TestDebugLog(TrebuchetLoggerTest.java:37)

1 test completed, 1 failed
```

My test looks like

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TrebuchetLoggerTest {
  TrebuchetLogger trebuchetLogger;
  @Mock TrebuchetClient trebuchetClient;
  @Mock Logger logger;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    trebuchetClient = mock(TrebuchetClient.class);
    when(trebuchetClient.launch(any(String.class))).thenReturn(true);
    logger = mock(Logger.class);
    trebuchetLogger = new TrebuchetLogger(trebuchetClient, logger);
  }

  @Test
  public void TestDebugLog() {
    trebuchetLogger.debug("debug-suffix", "some message", "arg1", "arg2");
    verify(logger).debug("some message", "arg1", "arg2");
  }
}
```

My code is:

```java
package com.common;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import lombok.NonNull;
import com.trebuchet.client.TrebuchetClient;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class TrebuchetLogger {
  @NonNull private TrebuchetClient trebuchetClient;
  @NonNull private Logger log;

  public void debug(String trebuchetSuffix, String format, Object... arguments) {
    if (trebuchetClient.launch(trebuchetSuffix)) {
      log.debug(format, arguments);
    }
  }

  public void info(String trebuchetSuffix, String format, Object... arguments) {
    if (trebuchetClient.launch(trebuchetSuffix)) {
      log.info(format, arguments);
    }
  }

  public void warn(String trebuchetSuffix, String format, Object... arguments) {
    if (trebuchetClient.launch(trebuchetSuffix)) {
      log.warn(format, arguments);
    }
  }

  public void error(String trebuchetSuffix, String format, Object... arguments) {
    if (trebuchetClient.launch(trebuchetSuffix)) {
      log.error(format, arguments);
    }
  }
}
```

Why does my mockito mock fail with seemingly identical results in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling different overloads in your SUT and verify.

```java
// SUT
log.debug(format, arguments);

// Test
verify(logger).debug("some message", "arg1", "arg2");
```

correspond to overloads:

- [debug​(String format, Object... arguments)](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#debug(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))
- [debug​(String format, Object arg1, Object arg2)](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#debug(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object))

If you need to call varargs-overload when you have a format and 2 arguments, you need to pass the arguments as an array.